# VB.net Console - Displaying a random number that was generated

Tags: vb.net, random, numbers, basic

I'm making a simple text based adventure in VB.net console that includes combat. In the fight scenes I want the game to generate a random number that determines how much damage you.
This is my current code:

```
Module Module1
    Dim rng As New Random
    Dim strmod As Integer = 1
    Dim yourhit As Integer

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Welocome to the training grounds!")
        yourhit = (rng.Next(1, 4) + strmod)
        Console.WriteLine("You hit the dummy and deal {0} damage to it!",
                          yourhit)

    End Sub
End Module
```

Now i'm wondering if its possible for my randomly generated number to be displayed without it being entered into another variable (in this case the *yourhit* variable). I've tried simply by having *rng* instead of *yourhit* but that a message saying *You hit the dummy and deal System.Random damage to it!*

I'm new to visual basic so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to do:

```
Console.WriteLine("You hit the dummy and deal {0} damage to it!",
                  (rng.Next(1, 4) + strmod))
```

Comment: But what if I want to reuse the number that will be rolled here later? Is it possible for me to somehow do that?
EDIT: I want to create an HP system so I want the number to display to the user and then I want the same number to be deducted from a set number.

Comment: Variables are intended for reuse, that's why they exist. If that's your intention then your original code is correct.

Comment: Alright, thank you then. I was not sure if I did it right so I asked just in case.